# After choosing Darcula theme on first run, AppCode does not give me a choice to use the XCode theme as it did before

Tags: appcode

I am evaluating AppCode and I just ran into something that is not a big deal but kind of irking me.

When I started the program, it asked me to choose a theme. I chose Darcula because it usually is a solid choice.

Another choice was XCode. This was tempting because of familiarity - I was actually worried that Darcula would feel "wrong" but instead of going with my gut I just went with Darcula.

Now, I don't like Darcula. At all. When it comes to swift development that is, on this IDE, for some stupid reason.

But I cannot change back to XCode! It's not an option - the only options seem to be "Default" and "Darcula" - and Default doesn't quite feel like XCode theme looked like.

Is XCode theme gone forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, see, theme chooser in AppCode is different than in other JetBrains products - it allows you to select the theme for all IDE components, editor and keycap behaviour at the same time. So, in short, choices are:

- Darcula = Darcula UI theme + Darcula editor theme + JetBrains keymap
- Default (light) = Default UI theme + Default editor theme + JetBrains keymap
- Xcode = Default UI theme + Xcode editor theme + Keymap which is similar to Xcode

So, to use same settings as for Xcode theme on start theme you should do the following:

1. Navigate to Preferences -> Appearance -> Theme and select "Default"
2. Navigate to Preferences -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> General -> Scheme and select Xcode
3. If you prefer Xcode key bindings - you can also change keymap in Preferences -> Keymap.